# How to maintain WordPress permalink structure with custom content with URL parameters?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, customization

Lets say I have posts, pages, plugins and navigation etc. from WordPress. Then I have a Video on Demand Archive now I want use WordPress (core, plugins, theme) to process and display this content. Lets also assume my permalink structure is `/%postname%/`.

I'm currently mixing content using page templates to show content via *(mydomain.com/page/?video=12435)* URL parameters. Every ID presents an individual page.

How to convert the URL-parameters to match my permalink structure? Can I solve this problem with WordPress code?

Comment: Search this site for "endpoint". I think that will get you started.

Comment: @s_ha_dum You're right. Now that I repharesed the question I'm also "surprise, surprise" getting more relevant results from the search.

Comment: After you've done some research, [edit] the question with more detail and your chances of a solid answer will improve.